# gtk3: How to propagate key-events/accelerators (shortcuts) from local to global?

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

## Setup

This is the (example) GUI situation:

- Window

  - GtkEntry
  - Menu

    - MenuItem (Accelerator: <kbd>backspace</kbd> )

I'm using `gtk_window_add_accel_group` and `gtk_widget_add_accelerator` for the accelerator setup.

### Problem

When I hit <kbd>backspace</kbd> within the `GtkEntry` the accelerator gets activated.

### Goal

#### Goal For this example

If backspace is hit within the GtkEntry, it should act as usual and remove a character. If any other widget is focused, the accelerator should get activated.

#### Goal in general

The goal is to have a behavior, where local widgets have a higher priority regarding input, than global widgets. Local means "focussed" or their parents.
E.g.

- Window

  - Widget1

    - Widget2

      - Widget3
      - GtkEntry (focussed)

The propagation chain for input should be:

GtkEntry, Widget3, Widget2, Widget1, Window.

## Regarding answers

- I know you could disconnect the specific accelerator group. But this is not an acceptable solution. General reason is code cleanness. Concrete reasons given below.

  - GtkEntry has to know about functionality, that is not within it's scope.
  - If there are many accelerator groups, they all have to be dis- and reconnected.
  - If the accelerators are user-defined, it's not even clear which accelerator groups have to be disconnected.
- If this is not possible with gtk, I'd appreciate that information as well.

## Code

The following is the full code.

```
#include <gdk/gdkkeysyms.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

  // ======= setup window generalls =====
  GtkWindow *window = (GtkWindow*)gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);

  // ======= create vertical layout =======
  GtkWidget *vbox = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 0);
  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window),vbox);

  // ======= create GtkEntry =======
  gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox), (GtkWidget*)gtk_entry_new(), FALSE, FALSE, 0);

  // ======= create menu bar =======
  {
    GtkMenu *menubar = (GtkMenu*)gtk_menu_bar_new();
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox), (GtkWidget*)menubar, FALSE, FALSE, 0);

    // create a new menu item in menu bar
    GtkMenuItem *menuTitle = (GtkMenuItem *)gtk_menu_item_new_with_label("MenuBarItem");
    gtk_menu_shell_append(GTK_MENU_SHELL(menubar), (GtkWidget*)menuTitle);
    {
      // create a new dropdown menu
      GtkMenu *menu = (GtkMenu *)gtk_menu_new();
      gtk_menu_item_set_submenu(menuTitle,(GtkWidget*)menu);
      {
        GtkWidget *menuItem4 = gtk_menu_item_new_with_label("Quit");
        gtk_menu_shell_append(GTK_MENU_SHELL(menu), menuItem4);
        g_signal_connect(menuItem4, "activate", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

        GtkAccelGroup *accelGroup = gtk_accel_group_new();
        gtk_window_add_accel_group(GTK_WINDOW(window), accelGroup);
        gtk_widget_add_accelerator(menuItem4, "activate", accelGroup, 
                  GDK_KEY_BackSpace , (GdkModifierType)0, GTK_ACCEL_VISIBLE);
      }
    }    
  }

  gtk_widget_show_all ((GtkWidget*)window);
  gtk_main();

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just hook into the `key-press-event` and `key-release-event` of the window:

```
g_signal_connect(window,"key-press-event",G_CALLBACK(gtk_window_propagate_key_event),NULL);
g_signal_connect(window,"key-release-event",G_CALLBACK(gtk_window_propagate_key_event),NULL);
```

`gtk_window_propagate_key_event` will do all the work for you ( including the check for a focused widget stuff)

#### Remarks

- This method also works in conjunction with `gtk_application_set_accels_for_action` (because app-accelerators are apparently registered at the window)
- Quote from gtk help: "fighting gtk over key events is unlikely to spark happiness"

#### This method is currently used in

- Nautilus (gnome)

  - (the concrete implementation differs by the time being)